# infinite recursion when querying sql using repository in jpa hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have two entity, `Promotion` which contains information about a promotion and `Promotion Details` which contains list of products in a `Promotion`. Below is my code.

**Promotion Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Promotion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "promotion")
    private List<PromotionDetails> details;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date endDate;
}
```

**PromotionDetails Entity:**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PromotionDetailsPK.class)
@Data
public class PromotionDetails {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "promotion_id", referencedColumnName = "promotion_id")
    private Promotion promotion;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Column()
    private double discount;

}
```

I want to retrieve one `Promotion` which is available for a product using JPA.

**PromotionRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface PromotionRepository extends JpaRepository<Promotion, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT promotion "
            + "FROM Promotion promotion "
            + "INNER JOIN promotion.details details "
            + "WHERE details.product.id = :productId "
            + "AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN promotion.startDate AND promotion.endDate")
    Promotion findOneByProductId(@Param("productId") Long productId);

}
```

But this error occured:

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.entity.PromotionDetails.toString(PromotionDetails.java:18)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:527)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.entity.Promotion.toString(Promotion.java:18)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.entity.PromotionDetails.toString(PromotionDetails.java:18)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:527)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.entity.Promotion.toString(Promotion.java:18)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.worksap.stm.entity.sales.PromotionDetails.toString(PromotionDetails.java:18)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:527)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.worksap.stm.entity.sales.Promotion.toString(Promotion.java:18)
```

I know it seems like `Promotion` is calling `PromotionDetails` and `PromotionDetails` is calling `Promotion` and so on. But, how do I fix this?

**--EDIT--**

I would like to add something. I am using Lombok to generate Getter, Setter, and toString

Comment: please show us the toString method in the Entity Promition and the toString of PromotionDetails. There the endless loop started! at com.example.entity.Promotion.toString(Promotion.java:18)

Comment: hmm, I am using lombok to generate it

Comment: Then perhaps exclude the linked entity: @ToString(exclude="id") ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can exclude fields from the ToString generation in Lombok. For that, you have to add the `@ToString` annotation to your class and add the fields, which you want to exclude. In your case, i would exclude the field `details` in the `Promotion` class:

```
@ToString(exclude="details")
public class Promotion {}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
com.example.entity.PromotionDetails.toString(PromotionDetails.java:18)
.
.
.
jp.co.worksap.stm.entity.sales.Promotion.toString(Promotion.java:18)
```

You have a recursive call on the `toString()` of both entities I guess, 
`PromotionDetails` is trying to print `Promotion` while `Promotion` is trying to print all its `PromotionsDetails`

A solution would be :
 Remove either `Promotion` value from the `PromotionDetails` `toString()` method or remove `PromotionDetails` from the `toString()` of `Promotion`.

Becareful with `toString()` presentation of entities it can cause you trouble.